# Encoding Issue while scr

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, character-encoding

I just want to scrape chinese language data.Everything is going good I have got and encoding issue while I run the program its print properly on terminal but I save into csv then I will get some wierd symbols. Is there any way to get rid of?

Here is terminal result:
{'Name': ' 『受注生産』KREX コラボフーディー'}

In Csv:

ã€Žå—æ³¨ç”Ÿç”£ã€KREX ã‚³ãƒ©ãƒœãƒ•ãƒ¼ãƒ‡ã‚£ãƒ¼

We get that type of wierd symbol

Comment: Are you opening the CSV in excel or in notepad?

Comment: In microsoft excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the CSV but Microsoft Excel itself. I have faced similar issue, if you open the file in a text editor, you will notice the characters are in correct encoding. But opening the CSV directly in Excel will not work.

To overcome the issue, you should open a new spreadsheet, go to data tab and click on `From Text`

[image: Data Open]

Then select File Origin as UTF-8

[image: File Origin]

And then select `Comma` option

[image: Delimiter]

Once done, you will see the correct data in Excel with proper encoding

Comment: I didn't understand could you please explain?

Comment: @HarisJameel, I have updated the answer a bit to make it easier to understand